# Force text/background color in text fields in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

On some websites when there is a text input area, the colors comply with my theme, i.e. white text on dark background. But in other websites, such as [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for example, the input field background is white, with very light grey text. This combination is almost unreadable.

Is there a way to force all websites to use `color_X` for background and `color_Y` for text in input fields (text areas) ?

I presume this can be modified in `userChrome.css` or a similar file, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own CSS (style sheets) and enable it using something like [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), and include a couple of lines such as:

```
input,textarea { color: #000 !important; background-color: #fff !important; }
```

Where input and textarea are the HTML objects you want to change, and and `#fff` and `#000` are shorthand hex codes for white and black respectively. The `!important` tag is to override any other style from the website in question.

If you could rather not install extra addons, I belive you could directly add the same CSS to the `userContent.css` file in your user profile directory to achieve the same results.